# WP menu implementation with dropdown

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, nav, wp-mega-menu

In Wordpress custom theme, Nav bar have a dropdown. Now I implement that wp menu by three menu, First two links one menu Dropdown one menu and last two links are one menu. There is three menu but I need to do that by one single menu. Problem is how to do dropdown. Custom theme developed by tailwindCSS

I need to implement nav menu with dropdown by one single wp menu.

```
<div id="navigation">
                  
                <ul class="navigation-menu nav-light">
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/home ?>" class="text-gray-700 font-mulish active:text-yellow-500">Home</a></li>

                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/about-us ?>" class="text-gray-700 sub-menu-item font-mulish active:text-yellow-500">About</a></li>
                    <li class="has-submenu parent-parent-menu-item>">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a><span class="menu-arrow"></span> 

                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/1 ?>"></a>1</li>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/2 ?>"></a>2</li>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/3 ?>"></a>3</li>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/4 ?>"></a>4</li>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/5 ?>"></a>5</li>
                                    <li><a class="sub-menu-item " aria-current="page" href="<?php ebloginfo('url'); ?>/6 ?>"></a>6</li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/case-study ?>" class="text-gray-700 font-mulish active:text-yellow-500">Case Study</a></li>

                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Contact-us ?>" class="text-gray-700 sub-menu-item font-mulish active:text-yellow-500">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```